# Error logging in to org.eclipse.ui when running .xml file with testNG suite.

Tags: eclipse, testng

If I create a test class to use through testng everything works fine as expected. If I then try to run this test via a .xml file then I get the following error log. I am certain all my packages and classes are labelled correctly. I have tried un-installing and reinstalling eclipse and making new workspaces too and trying it with multiple different classes and packages but I always get the same error.

I am running Eclipse Mars on a 64-bit Windows 7.

Thanks.

The following data will be sent:

```
------
STATUS
------
pluginId            org.eclipse.ui
pluginVersion       3.107.0.v20150507-1945
code                0
severity            4
message             Unhandled event loop exception
fingerprint         3ed0857c

Exception:java.lang.NullPointerException: null
     at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
     at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
     at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
     at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
     at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
     at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
     at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchShortcutExtension.launch(LaunchShortcutExtension.java:431)
     at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.actions.LaunchShortcutAction.run(LaunchShortcutAction.java:74)
     at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.actions.LaunchShortcutAction.runWithEvent(LaunchShortcutAction.java:123)
     at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
     at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
     at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1137)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1122)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:788)
     at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$9.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:1293)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
     at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
     at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
     at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
     at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:654)
     at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:598)
     at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(null:-2)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(null:-1)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(null:-1)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(null:-1)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)

------
REPORT
------
anonymousId         3741d217-639d-4c96-970a-231ce281c5eb
name                
email               
comment             
eclipseBuildId      4.5.1.M20150904-0015
eclipseProduct      org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
javaRuntimeVersion  1.8.0_60-b27
osgiWs              win32
osgiOs              Windows7
osgiOsVersion       6.1.0
osgiArch            x86_64
logMessage          false
ignoreSimilar       false

-------
BUNDLES
-------
name                org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable
version             1.5.0.v20150422-0725

name                org.eclipse.core.databinding
version             1.5.0.v20150422-0725

name                org.eclipse.core.runtime
version             3.11.1.v20150903-1804

name                org.eclipse.debug.ui
version             3.11.100.v20150731-1137

name                org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench
version             1.3.0.v20150531-1948

name                org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt
version             0.13.0.v20150504-0621

name                org.eclipse.equinox.app
version             1.3.300.v20150423-1356

name                org.eclipse.equinox.launcher
version             1.3.100.v20150511-1540

name                org.eclipse.jface
version             3.11.0.v20150602-1400

name                org.eclipse.swt
version             3.104.1.v20150825-0743

name                org.eclipse.ui
version             3.107.0.v20150507-1945

name                org.eclipse.ui.ide.application
version             1.1.0.v20150422-0725

name                org.eclipse.ui.ide
version             3.11.0.v20150825-2158

name                org.testng.eclipse
version             6.9.7.201510070420
```

Comment: Can you share the (relevant) source files of the project? Just from the error it is hard to see what's wrong. I've validated Eclipse Mars (4.5.1) with TestNG (9.6.7.201510070420), running the TestNG test through Eclipse as well as through Maven with testng.xml file.

Comment: This is the class I am using to test:

package Test1;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class NewTest {
  @Test
  public void testOne() {
   System.out.println("Run this.");
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

This is the class I am using:

```
package Test1;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class NewTest {
  @Test
  public void testOne() {
      System.out.println("Run this.");
  }
}
```

and then I right click the class, navigate to TestNG and Convert to TestNG.

testng.xml then appears under my project folder (not within any sub folders of the project) and testng.xml reads as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="none">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="Test1.NewTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Comment: I should add that if I right click on the .xml file and go Run As, Run Configurations and then run, then the test works fine and I don't get any errors.

Comment: Also if I run the .xml file from command prompt then it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of Eclipse Mars (v4.5) in combination with TestNG () has indeed a [bug](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/820). See the comments in the bug, as there is a [workaround](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/820).

Same question with similar workaround: [Run as TestNG Suite not working in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33050286/run-as-testng-suite-not-working-in-eclipse).