# Run as TestNG Suite not working in eclipse

Tags: testng

I am learning TestNG and working on parameterization. I created a new java class and then I created a new testng.xml file. I included the class name in the xml file. But I tried to run the testNG.xml file as TestNG Suite nothing will work.

Please see to the java class,

```
 public class Test1 {

 @Test
 public void test_Firefox()
 {
    System.out.println("Test_Firefox method..");
 }
}
```

Testng.xml file,

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >
 <test name="Test" >
   <classes>
      <class name="com.multibrowser.Test1" />
   </classes>
 </test>
</suite>
```

Folder structure,
[image]

Please help me in this.

Comment: did you get this working ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure Why did you created your suite file under "Referenced Libraries"

create it under "com.multibrowser" package. or under  another folder.

take a look at screenshot below, testng-suite.xml.

[image]

---

Right click your suite file, click Run as -> Run Configurations.
you will some thing like below,

[image]

Right Click testng and give new, Then choose your suite and give run, as per screenshot. 
[image]

Comment: If its not helping, comment here. we have to check  whether proper Jar are added to library path,

Comment: I created the testng.xml file in com.multibrowser package now as you said. But still nothing iw working for me. I have updated Testng to its latest version. I am using Java 1.7 and Eclipse luna.

Comment: It is working for me only when I do as you mentioned(through run configurations). But again coming back to project folder and trying to run it as testng suite nothing will work. Every time should I do the same ?

Comment: Yes if you want to run the suite. You have to select suite.

Comment: If I need to run just class by right click, what needs to be done ?